# Is there a way to see which files were purchased in the iTunes store?

Tags: itunes, itunes-store

I would like to sort my iTunes library according to the login that was used to purchase the file at the iTunes store.

I purchased a few items a few years ago on a login that I have long since forgotten. I have tried the Apple password reminder feature, but none of the emails that I thought were plausible accounts I had used to create my iTunes account were registered in iTunes.

Every time I try to move my library, those few files purchased in the old login give me headaches. I would like to delete the files from my library permanently, but I need a way to sort them out.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Unless the items purchased with your obsolete iTunes Store account are too many and hard to identify, I would delete these apps one by one from the iTunes library, then re-purchase them with your current iTunes Store account via iTunes. Finally sync any device to which the apps go to so that you have all on one account.

I don't think you can in any way transfer an already purchased item from one account to the next, let alone sort the apps in the order you have specified in your question.